# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "value " at path "value"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas users and messages. When i try to insert in to messages schema it throws subject error. My expectation is that it should add the _Id of user in messages schema, but i am unable to figure it out. I dont know its throwing validation error.
This is my users schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: String, createIndexes: { unique: true, required: true, trim: true } },
  imagePath: String,
  name: {
    first: String,
    middle: String,
    last: String,
  },
  mobileNumber: String,
  onlineStatus: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Online'
  },
  accountStatus: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Active'
  },
  lastSeen: Date,
  socketId: String,
  pushToken: String,
  country: String,
  city: String,
  ipAddress: String,
  timeZong: String,
  continent: String,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  lastUpdated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }

});


UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = new Date().now;
  }
  if (!this.accountStatus) {
    this.accountStatus = "Active";
  }
  next();
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema)
```

**this is messages schema**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose')
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    message: String,
    messageTo:
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users",
        required: 'To id cannot be empty',
    },
    messageFrom:
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users",
        required: 'From id cannot be empty',
    },
    messageRead: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    receiverDeleted: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    senderDeleted: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    sendDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    receivedDate: Date
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Messages', userSchema)
```

this is how i am trying to insert.

```
var message = new ModelMessages();
message.message = params.message;
message.messageTo = params.messageTo;
message.messageFrom = params.messageFrom;
message.save((err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        logger.error(`Unable to send IM. ${err} Stacktrace: ${err.stack}`);
    } else if (doc) {
        logger.info(`Sending message to recievers.`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that `params.MessageTo` and `params.messageFrom` are of type ObjectId before the assingment:

```js
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
try {
  message.messageTo = ObjectId(params.MessageTo)
  message.messageFrom = ObjectId(params.messageFrom)
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the id is valid or not

`mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('your id here');`

But there is a case of even a 12 byte string can be valid by the above method. Your `messageTo` and `messageFrom` are not the mongoose id type

Or you can even change the type to `string` even

Answer (score 0):

in my program this error occurred because of

before(error):

```
<a href="/admin/posts/edit/**:**{{_id}}">
   <button class="btn btn-success mt-4">Edit post</button>
</a><br>
```

after(success):

```
<a href="/admin/posts/edit/{{_id}}">
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-4">Edit post</button>
</a><br>
```

try to find something similar in your program.